# How to fetch the created video file content in android marshmallow

Tags: android, video, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-contentresolver

I am working on video editing app via ffmpeg. I am able to fetch the video content such as ID, DATA, DISPLAY_NAME, Size, and duration in all android version except Marshmallow. I have also given the read write permission at Runtime.

Below is the code I am using to fetch the video content via ContentResolver.

I would really appreciate any help.

```
 public static VideoModelLocal getVideoModelFromPath(Context context, String filepath) {
    VideoModelLocal model = null;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.SIZE,
    };
    String[] selectionArgs = {filepath};
    String selection = MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + "=?";
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    Log.e("cursor count", "" + c.getCount() + c);
    int vidsCount = 0;

    if (c != null) {
        vidsCount = c.getCount();
        Log.e("VIDEO count", "" + vidsCount);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.v("TAG", c.getString(0) + " : " + c.getString(1) + " : " + c.getString(2) + " : " + c.getString(3));

            String videoid = c.getString(0);
            String path = c.getString(1);
            String disName = c.getString(2);
            String duration = c.getString(3);
            long sizeinbytes = c.getLong(4);
            int size = (int) sizeinbytes / 1024;

            model = new VideoModelLocal(videoid, disName, duration, path, path, size);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return model;
}
```

Comment: There is no requirement for a video to be on a filesystem path that you can access. For example, it might be on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare I am actually creating this on a specific path in the internal storage directory

Comment: Yes, but that is not where the video is coming from. The `MediaStore` can index files that you do not have access to.

Comment: Okay, what should I do in this scenerio @CommonsWare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got an alternate

```
 public static VideoModelLocal getVideoModelFromPathViaFFMPEG(String path) {

    VideoModelLocal model = null;


    FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource("file://" + path);



    String duration = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);

    String disName = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_FILENAME);

    String size = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_FILESIZE);

    Log.e("TAG", "" + path);
    mmr.release();

    model = new VideoModelLocal("1", disName, duration, path, path, Integer.parseInt(size));

    return model;

}
```

**UPDATE**

Also need to add below code in gradle

```
compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.3'
```

Perfectly working in all versions :)